# Div Positioning IOS mobile different from other browsers

Tags: html, ios, css

Does anyone know how to fix the problem of iOS displaying elements in incorrect spots? I have a web app with two layers of divs superimposed on each other. It looks like the following on a desktop:

```
|--------------------------|
| |div1 - layer 1|         |
| |              |         |
| |              |         |
| |    |div2|    |         |
| |              |         |
| |--------------|         |
| |div3 - layer 1|         |
| |              |         |
| |              |         |
| |    |div4|    |         |
| |              |         |
| |--------------|         |
|--------------------------|
```

But on iOS, whether Safari/Firefox/Chrome, it looks like a less dramatic version of this:

```
|--------------------------|
| |div1 - layer 1|         |
| |              |         |
| |    |div2|    |         |
| |              |         |
| |              |         |
| |----|div4|----|         |
| |div3 - layer 1|         |
| |              |         |
| |              |         |
| |              |         |
| |              |         |
| |--------------|         |
|--------------------------|
```

And it happens whether I use absolute positioning, relative positioning, or whether I use px or em, or whether I use margin-top vs top. Nothing seems to fix it. Only moves the divs around a bit but the problem still exists.
Is this something others have encountered?

Pics (excluding sensitive info):

Desktop:
[image: Desktop, good]

iOS:
[image: iOS, bad]

HTML:

```
                                <div id="cdiv" class="fdiv">
                                    <label id="clabel"></label>
                                    <label id="cdatelabel"></label>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtcdate" onfocus="select()" class="txtfselect2" AutoPostBack="false" ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div id="fdiv" class="fdiv">
                                    <label id="flabel"></label>
                                    <button id="btnp" class="pbtn" onclick="return false;"></button>
                                    <button id="btnx" class="xbtn" onclick="return false;">X</button>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtfselect" onfocus="select()" class="txtfselect" AutoPostBack="false" ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                               <asp:GridView ID="gtSLdsf" runat="server" CssClass="gcf" CellPadding="0" ForeColor="#333333" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" ShowHeader="false">
                                    <Columns>
                                       </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                                <asp:GridView ID="gtSLdsffixed" runat="server" CssClass="gcfixedt" CellPadding="0" ForeColor="#333333" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeader="false">                       
                                    <Columns>
                                        </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
```

CSS:

```
#gtSLdsf{
margin-top:2px;
}
#gtSLdsffixed {
position: absolute;
border-right: 4px solid;
border-top: 1px solid;
left: 0px;
top:356px;
z-index: 1;
}
.gcfixedt td{
padding-left: 2px;
padding-right: 2px;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
}
#cdiv{
margin-top:-2px
}
.fdiv {
width: 300%;
position: relative;
left: 0px;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 0px !important;
background-color: #CECECE;
padding-left: 0px;
z-index: 1;
padding-top:3px;
min-height:30px;
}
#containdiv {
height: 100%;
position: relative;
pointer-events: all;
overflow: scroll;
margin-left: 28px;
padding-top: 4px;
}
.body {
height: 99vh;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 2px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: take care of the css float

Comment: Alright give me a few minutes. Page contains about 500 elements and I'll try to pull the relevant css.